# VB- How to search for a letter in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, datagridview

Basically, I want a label to record the number of times the "A" letter has been used in a specific column. i have made this code but it did not work. I am new to coding on VB- please help.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load
    Dim agrade As Integer = 0
    For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In dgvNames.Rows
        For i As Integer = 0 To rw.Cells.Count - 1
            If rw.Cells(i).Value = "A" Then
                agrade = +1
                lblA_star.Text = astar
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim nCol as Integer = ColumnIndexToScan           ' set this to the col index
Dim aCount As integer = 0

For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In dgvNames.Rows
    'For i As Integer = 0 To rw.Cells.Count - 1
        If rw.Cells(nCol).Text.ToUpper = "A" Then
            aCount  += 1
            lblA_star.Text = astar
        End If
    'Next
Next
```

Just dont iterate all columns.  The Question asks if a character has been USED (contains) but the code tested if the Column EQUALS the character